# Creating a 'Rough Match' Function

Tags: excel, vba

Suppose that I have a set list of words in rows A1....An (one per row) and that I have a set of sentences that I periodically pull from a source online.  I take one of these sentences and split it so that one word goes in every column from B onward until there are no more words to insert.  Right now I use a match function that tells me when the word in a specific row of column A matches a word in the sentence (the sentence now strung across columns B onward).  This works well for a single word, but is there a way to make this work for multiple words?  That is, if I have one pair of words (a,b) in rows A1....An respectively is there a way that I can tell Excel to find a 'rough' match?

Example:

I have the words apple--fruit in cell Ai and the words apple and fruit appear in columns B and C.  Is there a way that I can get Excel to notice that 'apple' is in the pair in cell Ai and produce a match?  What if the cell is harder to read, for example appledsjfruit?

Comment: Where are you currently placing your match formula?  ie. where is your result located?

Comment: You've tagged this "sentiment-analysis", which doesn't seem to apply, and "VBA", which doesn't seem necessary, as you've described the problem. Do we need more details in order to understand the tags?

Comment: Sorry about that Doug, I initially made this post with the intention of using a sentiment analysis example, but I decided the above example would be far simpler.  And thanks pnuts, I'll check that out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need VBA for this. Enter this in D1 as an [array formula](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/array.htm) with <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>shift</kbd>-<kbd>enter</kbd>:

```
=SUM(COUNTIF(A1,"*"&B1:C1&"*"))>0
```

The asterisks are wildcards, and the array formula, in effect, loops through each cell in `B1:C1`. So the formula says to count the instances of B1 or C1, preceded and followed by any text, found in A1.

Comment: Thanks Doug.  I'm not sure I understand why you chose to use count if, and I'm not sure what the * is used for, would you be able to explain further?

Comment: Woops, that doesn't work, or rather only if the first cell, `B1` is a match.

Comment: I forgot the `SUM` part. Fixed now.